# SQL query to count grouping by table attributes

Tags: mysql, sql

I've got the following table:

```
create table client(
   name varchar(50),
   red tinyint(1),
   green tinyint(1),
   blue tinyint(1)
);
```

I want to count how many people has red, green and then blue products. (Products can be red, green and blue at the same time, or any kind of combinantion).
I know I must do 3 counts, but I wonder if there is any kind of query that has this as an output:

```
Product type  - Number
red           - 100
green         - 223
blue          - 23
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Will it work for you :

```
SELECT 
COUNT(CASE WHEN red=1 THEN 1 END) as red_cnt,
COUNT(CASE WHEN green=1 THEN 1 END) as green_cnt,
COUNT(CASE WHEN blue=1 THEN 1 END) as blue_cnt
FROM table1
```

Then you can display it the way you want on client side. Unfortunately, mysql doesn't support `PIVOT` or `WITH` so pivoting such result on server side will be too verbose. Another way which produces result set in the way you need is to use `UNION`. :
**Update**

I just realized there is another option:

```
SELECT a.product, 
   CASE a.product 
    WHEN 'Red' THEN b.red_cnt
    WHEN 'Blue' THEN b.blue_cnt
    WHEN 'Green' THEN b.green_cnt
   END as `Number`
  FROM 
   (
     SELECT 'Red' as product
     UNION ALL
     SELECT 'Blue'
     UNION ALL
     SELECT 'Green'
   )a
   LEFT JOIN
   (
     SELECT 
     COUNT(CASE WHEN red=1 THEN 1 END) as red_cnt,
     COUNT(CASE WHEN green=1 THEN 1 END) as green_cnt,
     COUNT(CASE WHEN blue=1 THEN 1 END) as blue_cnt
     FROM table1 
   )b ON (1=1)
```